# Nestjs, met some problems when using dependency injected class's method in interceptors, inject can't be resolved

Tags: dependency-injection, interceptor, nestjs

I injected a provider(FileFilter) in my controller, and I want to use its filter method in Interceptors.

```
@Controller('file-uploader')
export class FileUploaderController {

    constructor(private fileFilter: FileFilter) {}

    @Post()
    @UseInterceptors(
        FileInterceptor('file', {
            fileFilter: this.fileFilter.filter,
        }))

    uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
        return file;
    }
}
```

here is FileFilter

```
@Injectable()
export class FileFilter {
    filter(req: any, file: MulterFile, callback: any) {
        if (!file.mimetype.match(ASSESSMENT_FILE_TYPE)) {
            return callback(new HttpException(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST), false);
        }
        return callback(null, true);
    }

}
```

when I use postman to request the API, the error message is like the following:

```
fileFilter: this.fileFilter.filter,
[0]                          ^
[0] TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

BUT inside the post method, the filter can be used which means the FileFilter is injected correctly, then who can explain why this doesn't work in an interceptor? or is this about the init order or something? Help, please.

Comment: Someone help plz,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators have a different Lexical `this` which does not belong to the class, so `this.fileFilter.filter` is undefined as `this` does not have a property called `fileFilter`. I believe you would need to save the `filter` method as a function and not part of a class to use it like that